# Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256. error due to Signed Request cookie being empty

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

For some reason, the signed request cookie (fbsr_APP-ID, example: fbsr_121341354354354) is set **but** it is empty, so I'm getting `Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256.` errors.

I have been unable to reproduce this error, therefore I've added logging to the [getSignedRequest()](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L478) method from the PHP SDK.  After reviewing the logs:

- The fbsr_APP-ID cookie is set, but empty.  So it passes the validation inside [getSignedRequest()](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L478)
- The error appears on different pages, it's not localized to just one page or even a group of pages
- It happens on different browsers and to different users

Besides adding an empty check to `getSignedRequest` on a child class to remove the errors, not sure what's happening or what's a better solution.  Any hints? :)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256 spam in logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261606/unknown-algorithm-expected-hmac-sha256-spam-in-logs)